# Maximum clickable options #IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, html-select

There seem to be a limitation in the maximum number of clickable options in a select element.

If there is a select element with 3200+ options. Items from 3125 to N doesn't fire change event when they are clicked. However, items can be selected with the keyboard.

Any idea if this is a bug or a feature of IE8?. There is no such problem in IE6, IE7, FF or chrome.

Here is an example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Large select</title>
  <script>
  function loadData()
  {
    var s=document.getElementById('s');
    for(i=0;i<3500;i++)
      s.options[i]=new Option(i);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadData()">
<select id="s" multiple="multiple" size="20" onchange="alert('change')"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

**update**: I was trying this in ie8 beta (8.0.7000.0). It seems to work perfectly in ie8 final

Comment: Well.  It's nice to know that even in IE8 Beta the limit is much higher than any practical usable number of options.

Comment: why in the name of god do you have that many options in a single select... that is an absolutely horrendous user experience. Not to mention the increase in pageload/postback times. Have you no way to break this out into subfilters or use some sort of textbox autocomplete or Grid/paging/select functionality instead

Comment: Why do you care about it in a Beta anyway? It is a beta, it has bugs.

Comment: Yes, I know so many options in one select is not the most usable thing of the world. And the fact is that right now is working with tons of options and I'm changing it so you can filter by text and show you only a few options (the most frequent), but with one last option "more..." that refresh the select and add more options.

Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is no such problem in ...

Problem?! Am I the only SO user scared of the beast you're creating?

Just out of curiosity, why on earth do you have so many options?

**Edit:** Don't get me wrong, it's fun to learn the upper limits of things. But now I've seen this now works in IE8 final, my next website is going to have at least 6000 `<options>` in any `<select>` I use!

Rock on!

Answer (score 2):

It's yet another of those limitations that you should **NEVER** hit. Just like the maximum number of columns in a database table. Even asking what the limit is indicates a terrible flaw in the design.